# How to add a div as a background for another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

My goal is to dynamically generate background images for divs.

I've got a function that:

- Draws an image on canvas;
- Gets data URL of the image;
- Creates a `bgDiv` with the image as background;
- Prepends the `bgDiv` to a given `div` element.

Here's the code of the 3rd and 4th points:

```
var bgDiv = document.createElement('div');
$(bgDiv).css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '0px',
    top: '0px',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    background: 'url(' + url + ')',
});
$(div).prepend(bgDiv);
```

The problem is: the `bgDiv` is drawn in front of children of `div`. I've figured out this is because of the `position: absolute` property, which is set on `bgDiv` while regular children in my case have no `position` set.

How can I get the `bgDiv` element to be drawn on the bottom of all children no matter what they are?

---

Disclaimer: I know that I could just set `background-image` property of `div`, but it's not sufficient for my purposes.

---

I'm testing this in recent Firefox, and I need quite universal solution.

Comment: use append instead of prepend **EDIT** after further inspection I believe what you need is to set the z index of bigDiv to -1

Comment: Why? Append causes `bgDiv` to be last among `div` children, so there's yet another reason why it should be drawn last, while I need it to be drawn first. I've tried this anyway, didn't work.

Comment: I've tried with `z-index`. `-1` causes it to not be drawn at all.

Comment: I made a simple test case with your code here http://jsfiddle.net/7sygP/, it appears to work with z-index, so in order to solve your issue we need an insight on your markup and css styles

Comment: It doesn't cause it not to be drawn; it probably falls below another element. In this case, just give the content div a higher z-index. As @koala_dev said, your markup is necessary. **EDIT:** `$(div)` doesn't seem like a valid selector. Try with the content div's ID instead

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7sygP/1/ - Ok, I know why `zIndex` doesn't work - I've got `backgroundColor` set on the main div.

Comment: Then you need to set a higher z index to the children of div http://jsfiddle.net/7sygP/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** if you're actually using `$(div)` as your selector, that's one problem. Use the content `<div>`'s ID or class instead.

**Edit 2:** If you're doing this multiple times (with different background images) I'd make `bgDiv` a class instead, then dynamically assign their positions. It will save you some JS.

bgDiv has to be "below" the rest of the div content, so give it a lower [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) than that of the content; this could cause it to fall underneath another element, however. In this case, set the content of the div to a higher z-index (and leave bgDiv's z-index to the default `auto`).

```
.bgDiv {
    position: 'absolute';
    z-index:-1;
    /* left: '0px'; Set in JS */
    /* top: '0px';  Set in JS */
    width: '100%';
    height: '100%';
    /* background: 'url(' + url + ')'; Set in JS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined your problem correctly in your question, you need to have bgDiv draw in a position lower than the children of div. In other words you need to set the z-index of all children to be higher, if you need to do this programatically then do

```
var bgDiv = $('<div class="bgDiv">').css('background', 'url(' + url + ')');
$(div).children().css({zIndex,2});
$(div).prepend(bgDiv);
```

With a defined class bgDiv in your CSS as @trojansdestroy suggested

```
.bgDiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
    width: '100%';
    height: '100%';
}
```